# x,y axis label values should be node label

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, nodes

I am new in tikz, I want to draw x,y axis and label of x,y axis should the node labels

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
    \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}   
    \begin{axis}[
separate axis lines,
y axis line style= { draw opacity=0 },
x axis line style={draw opacity=0 },     
      xmin=0,xmax=3,
      ymin=0,ymax=3,xstep=1,ystep=1,
      xtick={0,...,3},
 %     ytick={0,...,3},
 xticklabels={label-1,label-2,label-3,label-4},
      axis y line*=left,
      axis x line*=bottom,
      xlabel={$p_0$ (psi)},
      xlabel near ticks,
      ylabel near ticks,
      tick style={draw=none}
    ]
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to replace

```
 xticklabels={label-1,label-2,label-3,label-4}
```

By

```
\node [transform shape] (Label) at (1.5,4)[rotate=0,color=black] {label-1};
    \node [transform shape] (Label) at (1.5,5)[rotate=0,color=black] {label-2};
    \node [transform shape] (Label) at (1.5,6)[rotate=0,color=black] {label-3};
    \node [transform shape] (Label) at (1.5,7)[rotate=0,color=black] {label-4};
```

is it possible

Comment: can you post the whole code?

Comment: I don't the all code my requirement is node values eg:(label-1,label-2, e.t.c) should be the axis. It's just a sample code

Comment: That doesn't mean much to me so maybe somebody else understands this better.

Comment: I can't really understand the question... please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I don't understand it either. Show the complete code, perhaps a screenshot of the output, explain what you want to change, and what you want to change it to.

Comment: Is it ok now, please advise

Comment: I for one am still confused. If you don't want `pgfplots` to add xticklabels, use `xticklabels={}`, but the four nodes you specify will end up in the wrong place, and look exactly the same as your existing ticklabels. Do you just want to change how the ticklabels look? Can you try explaining what you actually want to achieve? Edit: Or do you want `yticklabels={label-1,label-2,label-3,label-4}`? Perhaps a sketch (made in e.g. Paint) could clarify things.